# doubt in example of left primitive ring.

Tags: noncommutative-algebra

According to Lam, let k be any division ring, V be a right k-vector space, and E=End(V), operating on the left of V.
then it says clearly V is faithful simple left E module, so E is left primitive ring.

My problem is with V being simple E-Module, as it is faithful because any endomorphism taking whole V to 0 is clearly 0 operator. but why is V is simple?
my guess is,
 let V has a proper E- sub module(non-zero) ,say W, then for any  φ in End(V),  φ(W) ⊆ W , which implies End(V) ⊆ End(W), not possible as W is a proper subspace of V.

please correct me and tell me what am i missing here. it could be very well trivial, i know.

Comment: Notice that your inclusions $End(V)\subseteq End(W)$ are mostly meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ring $E$ acts transitively on the set on non-zero elements of $V$, so there are no proper on-zero $E$-submodules.